# How to use looping construct to iterate some view ids?

Tags: java, android

Instead of doing the following,

```
ButtonHandler bh = new ButtonHandler();
findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(bh);
findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(bh);
findViewById(R.id.button3).setOnClickListener(bh);
```

that seems too verbose, I attempted to rewrite them as follows but fails.

```
ButtonHandler bh = new ButtonHandler();
for (int id : int[]{R.id.button1, R.id.button2, R.id.button3}) {
    findViewById(id).setOnClickListener(bh);
}
```

## Question

How to use looping construct to iterate some view ids as mentioned above?

[image]

Comment: It should not fail. What is the error message that you are getting there?

Comment: It should be int id, not int[] id

Comment: I think that's a typing mistake.

Comment: You need new int[]  when declaring the array, because you're allocating it.

Comment: @GabeSechan: Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ButtonHandler bh = new ButtonHandler();
int[] arr = {R.id.button1, R.id.button2, R.id.button3};
for (int id : arr) {
    findViewById(id).setOnClickListener(bh);
}
```

Just declaring the array outside resolved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can just access the ids directly

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    int id = R.id.class.getField("button" + i).getInt(0);
    tv[i] = (TextView)findViewById(id);
    tv[i].setOnClickListener(bh);
}
```

The trick here is that the R.class file is nothing complicated. By calling `R.id.something` you are accessing the field `something` inside `R.id` class.

Comment: If you already have to know how many of them there are and their name format, its less fragile and easier to maintain to just make an array of them.

Comment: @GabeSechan it's a matter of preference depending on the project and personal taste

Comment: I agree that your way will work, but it would be rejected in code review 100% of the time.  Its harder to understand, slower, more likely to break.  Its demonstrably worse.

Comment: Using hard coded string literals wastes the benefit of compile type check.